# types casting problems

Tags: c++, casting, virtual, dynamic-cast

Suppose you have base class `Unix_tree`, and derived `Unix_tree_type1`, `Unix_tree_type2` and so on. Why can't I cast `Unix_tree` to `Unix_tree_type`...? Is there a way to perform such a cast? Derived classes contain realizations of abstract methods, and their goal is to print data contained in base class in different ways. Thanks.

```
class Unix_tree
    {
    public:
        Unix_tree () 
        {
            tree_it.tree = &tree;
        }

        Unix_tree(const Unix_tree& utree) : num_of_files(utree.num_of_files), tree(utree.tree), tree_it(utree.tree_it) 
        {
            tree_it.tree = &tree;
        };

        int num_of_files;
        map<int, pair<int, string> > names;
        vector<pair<int, int> > edges;

        Tree< pair<int, string> > tree;
        TreeIterator< pair<int, string> > tree_it;

        string input_format;
        string output_format;

        static Unix_tree* load_tree(istream& input_info);
        void load_names(istream& input_info);
        void load_tree_nodes(vector<int>& levels);
        Unix_tree* convert(string format);

        virtual void load(istream& input_info) = 0;
        virtual void print_function(const Tree<pair<int, string> >* node, const vector<bool>& visited ) = 0;
        void print_tree();
    };


    class Unix_tree_type1 : public Unix_tree
    {
    public:

        void load(istream& input_info);
        void print_function(const Tree<pair<int, string> >* node, const vector<bool>& visited);
    };
```

Comment: Are you willing to modify the classes? Or do you want to know about casting with what already exists?

Comment: You cant instantiate `Unix_tree' because it contains a pure virtual function. so why would you need to cast to it?

Comment: Maybe i was a little sloppy, i am sorry. Suppose you have Unix_tree_type_1 and the goal is to cast it to Unix_tree_type_2.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast *pointers*, so:

```
Unix_tree *p = ...;
Unix_tree_type1 *q = (Unix_tree_type1*)p;
```

But I don't think you want to do that.  Method calls do what you want automatically, so:

```
Unix_tree *p = ...; // points to an instance of Unix_tree_type1
p->load(...);       // calls Unix_tree_type1::load, not Unix_tree::load
```

Comment: I don't know why but after dynamic_cast i receive pointer on object without data.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast, but you shouldn't. You should just call the member functions of an object pointed to by the base class and your implementations will be called. That's the point of virtual member functions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to cast a base class to a derived class because it would not make sense.  Without going into too much OO details, the purpose of inheriting from a base class is not just to "print data contained in base class" - rather, it is to provide a more specific implementation of functionality.  So imagine a "Fruit" class, that has the method "GetJuice()".  A class "Apple" that inherits from "Fruit" would likely be inheriting the method "GetJuice()".  However, in addition to that method, it can define other methods or properties such as "FindAppleWorm()", that would be specific to its type.  Therefore, when you have an Apple class, you can cast it to type fruit, and it would still make sense to call the Fruit class's "GetJuice()" method.  However, if you cast a Fruit class to the Apple class, you would expect to be able to call "FindAppleWorm()" method, but it would not be there.

The concept of inheritance in Object oriented languages compliments the concept of polymorphism.  I would recommend the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtype_polymorphism) to get a good introduction.

Comment: But there are cases where it would make sense.  For example, in the code `Fruit *p = ...; Apple* q = dynamic_cast<Apple>(p); if (q) { ... use q->FindAppleWorm() ...}`.

Answer (score 0):

Why you cannot? Of course you can - it's valid upcast, could be done by `dynamic_cast`. But you shall cast pointer or reference, not the type itself.

```
Unix_tree_type1* ptree1 = ...; // Some pointer initialization
Unix_tree* ptree2 = dynamic_cast<Unix_tree*>(ptree1);// Safe
Unix_tree* ptree3 = static_cast<Unix_tree*>(ptree1); // Also safe
```